# Apache: Load script based on hostname

Tags: apache-2.2

I don't think this is that complicated, but I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out the best way to go about it.

We have a site at `site.example.com` with 5 pages under it. Let's say those 5 pages are `site.othersite.com/page1.html, page2.html, page3.html, page4.html, page5.html`. Now, we also have 5 other subdomains, `lp1.OTHERSITE.com, lp2.othersite.com, lp3.othersite.com, lp4.othersite.com, lp5.othersite.com`. All of these domains are hosted on the same server, under the same document root. Now, what we need Apache to do is do a transparent redirect (IE the address bar does not change) to the following patterns:

```
lp1.othersite.com --> site.example.com/page1.html
lp2.othersite.com --> site.example.com/page2.html
lp3.othersite.com --> site.example.com/page3.html
lp4.othersite.com --> site.example.com/page4.html
lp5.othersite.com --> site.example.com/page5.html
```

Is this possible using solely Apache? If not, I have already written a PHP script to load the site.example.com/page*.html pages in an iframe based on the incoming hostname, but I'm unsure of how to tell Apache to send those 5 lp*.othersite.com domains to that PHP script.

I hope I'm explaining the project well enough. We basically need to redirect the lp* subdomains each to a different site.example.com/page*.html page without changing the address in the address bar.

Tips and advice would be appreciated. All I was able to make happen was for Apache to redirect those URLs to my PHP script, but the address bar changed and because it was a redirect, the address bar changed as well (At which point the PHP script didn't work, because the hostname had changed)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298530/redirect-without-changing-url-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a virtual host for each hostname, using the same `DocumentRoot`, but use:

```
DirectoryIndex page1.html
```

for lp1,

```
DirectoryIndex page2.html
```

for lp2 etc. so that those pages are used as the default page instead of `index.html`.

So e.g. `http://lp3.othersite.com/` will serve up `page3.html`. It will also allow you to navigate to `http://lp3.othersite.com/page1.html` etc. but the default page will be what you designate via the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Comment: This did the trick. I set up a vhost for each of the domains and pointed its directory index to our PHP script which loads content based on the hostname. Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but I think all your asking for is virtual hosts. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Virtual host require multiple DNS entries set to the same web server. Apache serves a designated page based on the DNS name used. The user sees the irk they typed unless you redirect.

Comment: We have a Vhost created for the main site already, and have added a ServerAlias for each of the lp* subdomains. So already, all of the necessary domains are pointing to the exact same document root. I just need to somehow tell Apache that whenever this exact hostname is being used to access this vhost, load up this page without changing the address in the bar. And whenever this other hostname is being used, load this other page without changing the address. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with URL Rewrite.  Just a quick off-the-cuff example (may or may not work):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lp([0-9]).othersite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page$1.html [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: See, I had this set up already similar to this, but it's performing an actual redirect and updating the address in the address bar. Other than that, this works fine. Is there a flag to load different content instead of doing a redirect? I tried using the [P] flag to proxy, but that, too, was updating the URL in the address bar.

Comment: Try the L flag, see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Follow [Apache Virtual Host documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/) to setup `VirtualHost` for each FQDN, then use [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) to set `DirectoryIndex`, and for redirect use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Tutorial:

[How To Create Temporary and Permanent Redirects with Apache and Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx)

Comment: This doesn't work because the address changes in the browser. The original address MUST remain.

Comment: @Kevin right, sorry i missed that part, well in that case you should use `mod_rewrite` and not `mod_alias`.